# Использование versus

Tags: падежи, сокращения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком падеже используются существительные при использовании сокращения *vs (лат. против)*? Например: грязевики vs фильтры (или фильтров?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

> После vs родительный падеж не употребляется. Правильно: индивид vs государство.